# Custom Permalink Structure for Pages & Posts

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages

I'd like to create a permalink structure that works in the following way:

Pages - http://myurl.com/*pagename*
Posts - http://myurl.com/news/*postname*/

How would I do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Settings" -> "Permalink" page and set custom structure for permalinks equals to `/news/%postname%`.

Answer (score 0):

When adding something like /news/%postname% to the permalink structure (you have to select "Custom" Permalink structure), I always think about how my users would "trust" this structure.

Most people are familiar with .html at the end, so I used to add this

**/%postname%.html** - for my regular posts

If you want something before that simply add it like suggested above

**/news/%postname%.html** - however that would appear on *all* posts.

You should consider to modify the Category base, it's on the same page yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php under Optional - by default it would show you /category/category-name on the frontend, so you can remove the /category/ from the URL there to get http://myurl.com/news/postname/ (you would then have to create a category "news" after changing the Category base)